# How can I copy text from a Word 2010 table into a VBA string, maintaining line breaks?

Tags: vba, string, ms-word, word-2010

I've got a table in Word with a cell with a few short lines in.  I want to copy the contents of that cell into a .txt file, maintining the line breaks.

Currently the line breaks are lost:
Contents of Word table cell:

```
Alice
Bob
```

Contents of VBA String:

```
AliceBob
```

Code sample to get string:

```
MyString = ActiveDocument.Tables(a).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text
```

Comment: As far as I recall, the break is not the full chr(13)+chr(10), vbCRLF, but only Chr(10), vbLF. You can check, and if that is the case, replace vbLF with vbCrLf.

Comment: Is the beak between the two words just due to wrapping?  Ie. there's no "hard" break in there?

Comment: @ Remou - When using the Range.Text there doesn't seem to be any characters at all between the end of one line and the beginning of the other.
@ Tim - There is a hard break - i.e. pressing enter.

Comment: The character chr(10) is not likely to be visible, you need to use something like `Instr(MyString,vblf)>0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using copy & paste into a new word document, then saving the new document as a text file.  Not neat or tidy, but effective enough for the situation.